# gem install buildr fails

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, buildr

I'm trying to install some dependencies for building a project on Windows 7. I've installed Cygwin with the Ruby dependencies I thought I needed.

When I run `gem install buildr` I receive the following error. Any suggestions?

```
$ gem install buildr
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing buildr:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for jni.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate
an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:58:in `create_rjb_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:77:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rjb-1.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rjb-1.4.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Can you please post the mkmf.log?

Comment: Are you using `RubyInstaller` binaries?

Comment: I'd recommend to use Buildr with JRuby. This eases the pain a lot since your only dependency is Java, which is usually available when you use Buildr to build Java projects, and you can avoid using the ruby-java bridge.

Answer (score 0):

Buildr is supported only with JRuby on Windows. You can install rjb on Windows but it is a painful process. JRuby is very fast (even faster on JDK7, kudos to the team), and you will probably be just fine that way.